# Kernel of augmentation map

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am studying Dummit & Foote Abstract algebra. And I have some problem.

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with 1 and let $G$={$g_1, g_2, \cdots g_n$} be a finite group. The map from $RG$ to $R$ defined by $\sum a_i g_i \rightarrow \sum a_i$ is an homomorphism. The kernel of this map is an augmentation ideal. For example, $g_i - g_j $is an element of the augmental ideal for all $i$, $j$. Another ideal in $RG$ is {$\sum a g_i | a \in R$}

Why those two examples are kernel of augmentation map? Doesn't the kernel has to become the subgroup of $RG$ where $\sum a_i =0$? Is there something I misunderstand?

Comment: They are giving **two** examples of ideals (i) the augmentation ideal, and (ii) the principal ideal generated by the "trace" element $\sum_{g\in G}g$. These ideals aren't the same.

Comment: @AnginaSeng The second example is not the example of augmentation ideal?

Comment: No, that's why they call it "Another ideal".